# Object comparison in ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a `select` that I populate using `ng-options` and `ng-model`.  The problem I have is that initially, the model is a copy of the data within the `ng-options` so my initial state is a blank `option` rather than the correct state of `ng-model`.  How can I make it so that it compares the models properly?  If I use an Id it becomes difficult to show the description

```
<select ng-options="role.Name for role in roles" ng-model="editingUser.Roles[0]"></select>
<span>{{editingUser.Roles[0].Description}}</span>
```

In C# I would overload the equality methods, is this possible in JS / Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular uses reference equality in that case. In your controller, iterate through the `roles` array to find the original corresponding to the copy that you have in `editingUser.Roles[0]`, and replace the copy by the original.

Answer (score 0):

Or if your roles contain an id you can just use **track by** in the ng-options attribute:

```
<select ng-options="role.Name for role in roles track by role.id"
ng-model="editingUser.Roles[0]"></select>
```